# Footer string not showing on view - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm having an issue trying to show the field string on my view, I'm trying to add two fields, to the footer of my view, and the fields are showing up, but not the strings. Here's my view:

```
<record id="book_contract_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">worksheet.form</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.worksheet.contract</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Contract Worksheet form">
          <header>
            <div class="oe_title">
            <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only" />
            <h1>
                <field name="name" />
            </h1>
            </div>
          </header>
            <sheet string="Contract Worksheet">
          <group >
            <group>
            <field name="date"/>
            <field name="book_block"/>
          </group>
          </group>
          <notebook>
        <page string="Specification - Description">
        <group>
          <group string="Paper for Text">
            <group>
            <field name="wt"/>
          </group>
        </group>
          <group string="Paper for Text">
            <group>
            <field name="gsm_sheet"/>
          </group>
        </group>
          <group string="Paper for Cover">
            <group>
            <field name="gsm_cover"/>
          </group>
        </group>
      </group>
      </page>
      <page string="Production Estimate - Printing">
        <group>
          <group string="Types">
            <group>
            <field name="printing_text_type"/>
          </group>
        </group>
          </page>
                        <page string="ISBNS">
                            <field name="isbns" colspan="4" nolabel="1" >
                                <tree string="ISBNS" editable="bottom"  create="false">
                                    <field name="name"/> 
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
         <page string="Production Estimate/Binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('additional_job', '!=', True)]}">
        <group>
          <group string="Lamination/Packeting">
            <field name="cost_rs18" />
          </group>
          <group string="Packing">
            <field name="cost_rs19" />
          </group>
          <group string="Other">
            <field name="cost_rs20" />
          </group>
          <group string="Total">
            <field name="total_totals" /> 
          </group>
        </group>
        </page>
      </notebook>
      <div class="footer">
        <field name="due_date" string="Due Date"/>
        <field name="total_totals" string="Total" />
      </div>
    </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

As You can see, I've put the `string` flag even on view, they have those strings on .py file as well, but they won't show up either.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to add it to inside any of the `<page>`.

Comment: If I Add it to page it doesn't appears at all :(

Comment: it will appears only in that page you have added

Comment: But I need it outside the pages... there is no way to accomplish that? In that case I guess I should add it to all the pages then, maybe... gonna try, Thanks

Comment: It doesn't appear on any page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by string you mean labels you should put your field inside a group.

```
 <div class="footer">
   <group>
    <field name="due_date" string="Due Date"/>
    <field name="total_totals" string="Total" />
    </group>
  </div>
```

Or add the 
labels

```
  <div class="footer">
     <label for="due_date"/>
    <field name="due_date" string="Due Date"/>
     <label for="total_totals"/>
    <field name="total_totals" string="Total" />
  </div>
```

Comment: lol, yes, I meant labels, sorry, ultra awesome, Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to you have used : `<div class="footer">`
Use "**`<footer>`**" tag insted of this. Might it will work..

Comment: Hi Keval, Thank You, but same result :/, really I don't get it, it's kind of weird